# Can I shrink a LUN on a Synology DS 409+ NAS iSCSI target

Tags: iscsi

I created a 3TB iSCSI target for all my Macs to use as a Time Machine Backup but would like to shrink it.  I don't want to delete it as then I would lose all the backups.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most SANs don't support shrinking LUNs as most file systems don't support shrinking volumes.  You'll probably need to create a new LUN then migrate the data then delete the old larger LUN.